# Can we rename a tag?

Tags: azure-data-catalog

We've created a number of *User Tags* in Azure Data Catalog (ADC). Once created, can they be renamed or can their spelling be changed?

When I right-click on the Tag I only get the options menu provided by the browser, not ADC features. I checked **Settings** and **Glossary** but can't see any rename options there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do a rename. It's only possible to delete and recreate.